# Unordered_set: remove with move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In c++11, std::unordered_set container provides both an insert overload and a new function emplace so that it can be used with non copy-constructible keys, for example std::unique_ptr.

What happens when you want to remove one of these keys? Is `auto temp = std::move(*some_iterator)` valid? Is there some function that allows us to erase an element and move it into a temp simultaneously?

Edit: I tried to keep it short, sweet and simple, but to be more clear:

- Is there an iterator adapter (possibly move_iterator?) that will let me move an element from a container, and erase that iterator?
- If not, why not? Shouldn't future c++ include this kind of interface?

The situation seems to be impossible: you cannot invalidate a key before removing it, and you cannot access it after removing it.

Comment: In C++11 `std::unordered_container` does not exists.

Comment: @Jefffrey typo, fixed

Comment: I suggest switching your data structure from `unordered_set<unique_ptr<T>>` to `unordered_map<T*, unique_ptr<T>>` so you can retrieve the `unique_ptr` before erasing: `auto temp = std::move(some_iterator->second);`.

Comment: @Casey that was only an example (chosen to be common) - I want to write generic code that can make use of non copy-constructible objects. It seems the api is asymmetrical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `std::unordered_set<T>` the member `emplace()` makes it unnecessary for the objects to be movable, either: you can `emplace()` non-movable objects into the container.

To answer the question: you can't `std::move()` elements out of a `std::unordered_set<T>` because the elements are all `const` and `const` objects can't be moved. When you `erase()` an `std::unique_ptr<T>` from an `std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<T>>` the pointed to object will be `delete`d: there is no interface which allows you to recover the pointer while `erase()`ing the element. Nor is there a `splice()` member to stick the element into another container where it can be ignored until it is time to get rid of it.

Comment: Yep - that's the situation I found myself in, I want to know if there is a way around. It seems you cannot invalidate an element before it is removed, and you cannot remove and element without deleting it. I asked this question because it looks like a catch-22 type situation. Unless you have a standard excerpt saying this is impossible, the answer isn't very useful, sorry.

Comment: @user3125280: There is no catch-22 situation at all! If you stick a `std::unique_ptr<T>` into a `std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<T>>` you won't be able to remove it from the container while keeping it alive. That is. What standard excerpt you want? The `std::unordered_set<T>` only gives access to `T const&` and no method to recover the as a non-`const` object. Put differently: what you _want_ cannot be done. You can do something akin what you want with a `std::unordered_map<T*, std::unique_ptr<T>>`, though: you can move the value there.

Comment: then how are they moved during a rehash? move assignment to const? if i can erase it, i should be able to move from it somehow..

Comment: @user3125280: Internally the unordered containers keep nodes embedding the actual objects (you can tell because pointers to elements are not invalidated by rehashing; only iterators are invalidated). That is, the actual objects stay put while some pointers are updated. That's why I commented on `splice()`: internally there is some form of list and I could have imagined that there is a way to move the nodes to a separate container but there isn't.

Comment: but if it gets deleted (even internally) than there is a mutable copy - which i can't access through any interface, no matter what?

Comment: @user3125280: you can destroy `const` objects, obviously, i.e., there isn't a need for a mutable object to be around. However, it is correct that there is no interface in `std::unordered_set<T>` which lets you get hold of an object being erased. Thinking of it - the object will be destroyed via an allocator: it might be possible to recover the objects using an allocator's `destroy()` member but even that may get a node with the `const` member embedded (I don't think it is mandated to destroy the actual value separately but I'm not sure).

Comment: better yet, if i can erase through a const_iterator/destroy through const pointer, shouldn't I be able to move and erase/ move and destroy? what if there was `key&& erase(iterator)` (dual to `iterator insert( key&&)`) - i think i will ask a more theoretical question in a minute. for now, accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simply to put the elements in `std::shared_ptr`. This way you can copy them around, and then eventually move the element out of the `shared_ptr`.

The cost of this, programming-wise, is that you have to define the hash function yourself.

Assuing you're putting `std::string` in the set:

```
struct MyHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& element) const
    {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(*element);
    }
};
```

And then you make the `unordered_set` like this:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string,MyHasher> the_set;
```

And now, you can move the elements around all you want.

Comment: The issue is the api supports inserting non-copy-constructible keys but not removing them. This is a limitation of move semantics. Moves are separate from destructors, so it is impossible to move from a constant object without destroying it twice (in this case calling delete twice on same pointer). In general either the api would need access to a mutable key (bad idea) or objects would need a combined move/destructor (bad idea) or programmers would just use copyable objects (good idea, but singletons should not be copyable) so in practice its a non issue.

Comment: if for some reason this kind of thing interests you, I asked about it in another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085735/are-move-semantics-incomplete)

Comment: @user3125280 Actually I fell into this issue, but `shared_ptr` was a good solution for my case. Thanks for the link :)