# Are move semantics incomplete?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-features, move-semantics

Move semantics replace copy semantics in situations where copying is inefficient. Copy semantics deals fully with copyable objects, including const objects.

Already, there exists a myriad of non-copyable objects in c++11, for example std::unique_ptr. These objects rely on move semantics completely because moving from an object allows for invalidating it. This is important (imho) for popular design patterns like RAII.

A problem occurs when a const non-copyable object is assigned to an area of memory. Such an object can't be recovered in any way.

This is obviously important during the lifetime of the object, because of its constness. At the end of it's lifetime, when the destructor is called however, the (non-existent) object is briefly non-const.

I suggest that a *moving* destructor could be a valuable addition to the move semantics model.

Consider a simple situation where an unique_ptr is used in an unordered_set. You can `insert` into this set using a move constructor (or construct "emplace"), however if you wanted to move this pointer to another unordered_set (i.e. keeping it const) it would be impossible.

Essential, there is a `iterator insert((possibly const) key&&)` but no `const key&& erase(iterator)`. In fact it would be impossible. The container could only be extended to return some pointer to the key, and forget about it.

A moving destructor could solve this ie `const MyClass&& ~MyClass()`, since it would only violate const during destruction (when the compiler considers the object is invalid anyway).

EDIT: I should point out`const MyClass&& ~MyClass() const` actually makes more sense. The destructor doesn't have to modify anyhting, only destroy the object as if it were no longer a valid handle to whatever resource it controlled.

Comment: Const objects are also non `const` during construction.

Comment: A more appropriate forum for this would be one of the first 2 on this page: http://isocpp.org/forums

Comment: Essentially it would copy only what it needs to (this is what move means in c++11) into a new object, and then destroys the old one, just like a normal move, but occuring but for a non-temp

Comment: @BenjaminLindley true, i guess i don't want discussion so much as 'not possible' or 'similar to this proposal'

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i posted the question elsewhere, time will tell if someone here wants to delete it, or answer it (or, you know, upvote it..)

Comment: A better example might be `struct foo { const std::unique_ptr<int> y; }`, and `std::unique_ptr<int> ~foo() const { return std::move(y); }` -- a structure that contains a `const` data member.  At destruction, you are allowed to mutate it.  In current C++ you could back door this: `struct foo { std::unique_ptr<int> y; std::unique_ptr<int>* dest; ~foo() { if (dest) *dest = std::move(y); } }` -- [live example](http://ideone.com/9vZVU8): the inability to "pass parameters to" a destructor means you have to add data members to do this.

Comment: @Yakk i only just read your comment now - yes, although i would prefer to be returning a foo. I had considered that hack (with const and copy ctor, get the dtor to check it doesn't free something twice) but it obviously isn't useful in generic code, etc. Really, the 'moving destructor' could be as simple as a const copy constructor that *doesn't* call the original destructor, since in some sense moving y is weird.

Comment: @user3125280 how about a function signature that takes `~C&` and thereby promises to destroy it?  This requires lots of gymnastics: amoung other things the variable type after the call changes (to aviid double destruction)!  And we need a way to do the 'rest' of the destruction code, and indicate which.

Comment: a copy constructor that promises to destroys it's only argument? that's definitely nicer syntax and work better for linking (and extensible if you wanted to merge two objects into one or something weird). hmm but then it would have to disassemble an object through a reference. the problem seems to be deriving from it still. (unless you consider lame ducks a solution). one solution would be to copy up the stack and destroy on the way back down, but then you need two functions and its ugly

Comment: Another observation: If an object is in read-only memory, then an attempt to move from it could cause serious problems. Maybe we need a new qualifier, `const-but-can-be-mutable-during-destruction`. :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imho you have identified a real need.

Your solution sounds a lot like what I have called *destructive move semantics*.  This possibility is described in the [original move semantics proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#Alternative%20move%20designs).  I think such a design is possible, though it is not without its problems.  As far as I know, no one is working this area on the standards committee.

There are simpler ways to extract move-only types out of the associative containers that would not require language changes (aside maybe from allowing type-punning without undefined behavior).

[N3645](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3645.pdf) is a library-only proposal which puts a nested `node_ptr` type into each container.  The `node_ptr` is a lot like a `unique_ptr`.  It has unique ownership of a node in an associative container.  But when you dereference it, you get non-const access to the `value_type` in the node, instead of the node itself.  `extract` and `insert` members are added to the associative containers allowing one to insert and remove nodes (owned by the `node_ptr`) to/from the containers.

You could use this to remove a node from a container, and then move a move-only type out of the node, and let `~node_ptr()` clean up the node when you are done with it.  The paper includes this example to demonstrate this functionality:

```
set<move_only_type> s;
s.emplace(...);
move_only_type mot = move(*s.extract(s.begin())); // extract, move, deallocate node
```

Note that `s.extract` is `noexcept`, as is `~node_ptr()` of course.  If the move construction of `move_only_type` is `noexcept`, then this whole operation is `noexcept`.  Otherwise if the move construction throws, the `set` is left as if the item had been erased from the `set`.

At the moment, no progress is being made on [N3645](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3645.pdf).  It has not been voted into a working draft, and I have no confidence that it ever will be.

**Update C++17**

I stand corrected:  The functionality I describe above was voted into C++17 with [P0083R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf).  Thanks to Cosme for reminding me of this in the comments below.

Comment: thanks, this is the kind of answer i was looking for. i understand the library could be changed to solve this particular example, but i hope people reading this realise it was just a particular example - yes "destructive move semantics" is exactly the problem i was trying to discuss

Comment: The last revision of the proposal mentioned above: [P0083R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but the premise is flawed.

An `unordered_set` doesn't actually hold `const` objects. It's just not giving you write access to the contained elements. That's a property of the accessors only.

It would be possible to add an `key erase(iterator)` function which just moves the element out to a temporary. I'm not sure why you'd want a `key&&` there.

As for `const MyClass&& ~MyClass() const`, that doesn't make sense for three reasons: dtors have neither return types nor CV classification, nor is overload resolution done for them.

Comment: of course it doens't make sense as it stands, that's not the question. "It would be possible to add an key erase(iterator) function which just moves the element out to a temporary." No. You can't move from a const, except with a const move operator. Such an operator is equivalent to a const copy operator. The problem is it can be invoked anywhere in code. Typically the non-copyable class is used to signal a unique object - how would "moving a temporary" work? what happens when the original, moved from object gets destroyed? It can't be modified so it frees whatever resource it was holding.

Comment: Basically, the only solution is to allow access to a handle to the memory (with its own pros and cons, and very un-generic, and fails to address the problem of where an object is deleted (see [here](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/c1y-move-copy-destructors.html) for someone else thoughts on a similar topic.)) or to provide some primitive that allows constructing from an object at the end of said objects lifetime (it is the only way to prevent double deleting, as would be caused by moving) and my suggestion one such possible primitive (only an example, i suspect there are better ways)

Comment: and also the unordered_set is just an example, (it can have const objects) and moving from an object would invalidate the hash (so effectively it must have const keys from an external perspective)

Comment: @user3125280: The set itself isn't const (obviously, since `erase` isn't const), nor are its members (You keep claiming they are, please provide actual proof. Ignore the accessors). And yet that's the only reason you give for such an important addition. Sorry, that's not enough justification in my book.

Comment: "the set itself isn't const" true (though you can delete through constant pointers, erase through const_iterator, etc) - consider moving from one key. The move creates and returns a new key. The old key is now modified. Critically, the previous key *may have a new hash*. The container doesn't know this, and has lost control of the element. Currently, we can't remove this except with a const copy constructor, agreed? But then the unchanged element is still deleted through its old destructor (which assumes it owns memory or something)

Comment: Nothing? Can we continue this in discussion? I understand you can redesign the container to have a key&& erase function, and similar containers, as one example. But this doesn't apply to all situations where there is a non-copyable const object. Sometimes, you are forced to use const objects for reasons beyond your control.

Comment: @user3125280: Your example took an element out; keeping its hash correct is pointless. The normal implementation would locate the node containing the element, remove that node from the hashtable, move the element to the return value, and discard the (now invalid) node. At no point in the operation is there an moved-from element in the hashtable.

Comment: ..i just said that.. (and obviously it would have to be in a new function, and wouldn't work with const types) - seeing as this is the only kind of answer i'm going to get, i'll delete the question.

Comment: -1, this really focusses on my (admittedly weak) example, rather than the question as a whole - the problem is better described in Howard's first link, for anyone still interested.

Comment: @user3125280: If you claim that a language feature is needed but are unable to provide a compelling argument, then the proposal will die. See Howard's response for another case where that happened.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>So basically you're saying it should be possible to move a `const` object into another `const` object and destroy the original?</strike>

Sorry but I think the whole **point** of making it `const` is to prevent this.

Otherwise it would form a loophole: you could destroy-move a `const` object out of its memory location, then you destroy-move *another* `const` object into the memory location of the first one (via placement `new`).

Now the object has **changed** even though it was `const`... so essentially `const` was useless.

See comments below...

Comment: yes, (calling different then normal destructor so the normal one doesn't get called twice). Actually that's not really a loophole, in the sense that you can already do that in c++. it is undefined behaviour and breaks some rules. I would have to look around more to give a definitive response, but I think that deleting the object means that it is no longer valid to access an object at that address (You would have to use hacks to keep that memory anyway while destroying the object there). Even if that object was const qualified. It is simply undefined. Let me make an ideone example..

Comment: [I tried](http://ideone.com/e.js/u3iWSQ) but it doesn't seem to have tricked the compiler (since it is illegal). I'm sure you know that people new to c++ often make the mistake of returning a reference to a temporary. This is the same situation. Once the object is out of scope or deleted by a pointer (or by a hypothetical destructor) it is invalid to access it in anyway. Const doesn't make an object permanent, only read only during it's lifetime.

Comment: @user3125280: Hmm, I'm pretty sure there's legal ways to do this, but interestingly I think the problem is even there right now and might have nothing to do with your proposal. For example `struct S { char x; };` `char buf[sizeof(S)];` `S const *p = new (buf) const S();` `foo(p);` `S moved(p->~S());` `new (buf) const S(moved.~S());` Whoops, we just modified the target of `p` even though it was constructed as a `const` object... maybe your proposal doesn't affect it after all?

Comment: @Mehrad that's what i meant - that code is undefined, the origianl const S has been destroyed. Trying to access it by P is wrong, even though it aliases with a new const S. This is programming error, and not a c++ error. Access to a destroyed object is always undefined.

Comment: @user3125280: Is it really undefined? This is POD, the destructor and constructor are trivial, so there is no notion of destruction or construction here. I'm pretty sure it's legal, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have a compilable example? It is legal, but may be undefined (I'll look) and even if it is not, it would be an error on the programmers part to think P was accessing the original - the reason I suspect it is undefined is because the compiler doesn't know that, so it breaches 'strict aliasing' rules (not sure if that is standard enforced in any way though)

Comment: @user3125280: You don't even need to break strict-aliasing. Something like this is sufficient to modify a const object (and yes this compiles fine): `int main() { struct S { unsigned char x; } s; new (&s) const S(); s.x = 1; /* whoops */ }`

Comment: took me a long time to remember #include <new> .. well it seem strict aliasing is *only* between different types, not different const instances of the same type. I wonder how compilers ensure constness then. Maybe they just work it out themselves, but that seems a very painful alternative.

Comment: @user3125280: lol yeah I ran into that problem too. I'm not sure, after seeing this I feel like `const` isn't all that useful after all...

Comment: Note that [basic.life]/7 makes it UB to use `p` in your first example, Mehrdad (not sure if you've already discussed that).

Comment: @dyp: Hmm why? Everything has a trivial destructor and constructor, so calling them has no effect, right? If it's OK to access it before the destructor is called then it has to be OK to access it afterwards...

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm talking about the passage that says that the pointer will refer to the newly created object (at the memory location where the old object resided). You cannot use this pointer to "manipulate" the new object (I guess *reading* is also prohibited) as the object contains const-qualified / reference members (hint: that means you cannot rebind ;).

Comment: @dyp: That passage you referred to starts with *"If, **after the lifetime of an object has ended**, [...]"* but if you read basic.life/4 it says *"A program may end the lifetime of any object by reusing the storage which the object occupies or by explicitly calling the destructor for an object of a class type **with a non-trivial destructor**."* Since the destructor is trivial here the lifetime has not ended, has it?

Comment: @Mehrdad [basic.life]/1 says dtor call **or** reusing storage. I'll add an answer to your question about rebinding, I think it's more approriate to discuss this issue there.

Comment: @dyp: What exactly constitutes "reusing" storage here? If instead of `new (buf) const S()` I had said `*(S *)&buf[0] = const S()` would that have been "assigning to the old storage" instead of "reusing the storage", since it's performing assignment instead of construction?

Comment: @dyp: Okay I'll talk with you there.

Comment: That looks like a call to `operator=` to me o.O

Comment: @dyp: Yeah, so that means I just modified the `const` object right?

Comment: Oh, *that* example also used a `const S` originally. Hmm yes, then you modify a `const` object. But that should be simply UB according to [dcl.type.cv]/4

Comment: @dyp: Hmm does this count as modifying the const object? I'm modifying the underlying memory... but I'm not casting away `const` or anything.

Comment: Haha, good point. Makes me wonder what an object is; it's a region of storage but has a lifetime, so you can create an object where another object has been... I'd say that generally `S const x{'a'}; const_cast<S&>(x) = S{'b'};` is UB. Also note that we're modifying the subobject, and the passage about `mutable` indicates we may not modify the subobjects of an objects defined as const either.